# jQuery: disable and enable touch with touchmove

Tags: jquery, touchmove

I use this code to disable and enable touch:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery("body").on("touchmove", false);

 jQuery('button').click(function(){
     jQuery("body").on("touchmove", true);
 });

});
```

function work fine for disabling touch but after click on button touch cannot be enable.

whats wrong on code?

Comment: What callback do you expect to be executed after clicking on the button?

Answer (score 11):

What is wrong is simply that you don't pass the argument required by [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You should pass a function (the event handler) and not just a boolean.

The simplest way to unbind then rebind is to have a boolean somewhere and test it in your handler. For example :

```
myapp = {active: true}; // change this boolean
jQuery("body").on("touchmove", function(e) {
    if (myapp.active) { // change myapp.active
        // do things
    }
});
```

If you want to unbind definitively, instead of passing `false` to `on`, use `off`. Passing `false` is a non documented trick that might break on future versions.

The `off` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) also contains an example of another way to bind/unbind a function on click :

```
function aClick() {
  $("div").show().fadeOut("slow");
}
$("#bind").click(function () {
  $("body").on("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Can Click!");
});
$("#unbind").click(function () {
  $("body").off("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Does nothing...");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

use `bind()` and `unbind()`

try this

```
 jQuery('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});

 jQuery('button').click(function(){
     jQuery('body').unbind('touchmove');
  });
```

Comment: This will not make any difference, since jQuery internally uses `on()` to `bind()` events. Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7/src/event.js#L965